NativeObject try-catch does not catch a timed out error
In the following code,
private bool AuthenticateUser(string userName, string password)
{
 try
 {
     using(var entry = new DirectoryEntry("myLDAP", userName, password))
     {
         // Attempt to bind to the directory entry
         object nativeObject = entry.NativeObject;
         return true; // Authentication succeeded
     }
 }
 catch(DirectoryServicesCOMException)
 {
     // Handle exception for failed authentication
     return false;
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
     // Handle other exceptions (logging, etc.)
     MessageBoxes.msgBoxOK(
         "Authentication Error",
         $"An error occurred: {ex.Message}",
         MessageBoxImage.Error);
     return false;
 }
}

I am getting a,

'System.DirectoryServices.DirectyEntry.NativeObject.get' times out and needed to be aborted in an unsafe way. This may have corrupted the target process.

But the error does not catch for either the catch(DirectoryServicesCOMException) or the general, catch(Exception ex)
Instead, the code continues in the block and returns true.
Any reason why the try-catch does not catch the timed out error?

I cannot explain the observed behavior, but as a workaround you could try to first set object nativeObject = null; then try to assign entry.NativeObject and finally return nativeObject is not null;

Thank you for the suggestion. Traveling at the moment but will definitely give it a try and give feedback when we arrive at our destination.

Also, does it make a difference if you change that line to this?: ActiveDs.IADsUser nativeObject = (ActiveDs.IADsUser)entry.NativeObject; You'll need to add a reference to the Active DS type library (Interop.ActiveDs.dll).

@OlivierJacot-Descombes
I tried
object nativeObject = null;  _ = entry.NativeObject; return nativeObject is not null;
but that unfortunately has the same behaviour. Thanks for the suggestion though.

@TawabWakil Thank you for the suggestion, but that too generates the same behaviour with the try-catch not catching the error.

It must be object nativeObject = null;  nativeObject = entry.NativeObject; return nativeObject is not null;. The idea is that if the the middle statement is aborted, nativeObject remains null but gets another value if the middle statement worked.

This is what I have discovered from here:

Binding against the AD has a serious overhead, the AD schema cache has to be loaded at the client (ADSI cache in the ADSI provider used by DirectoryServices). This is both network, and AD server, resource consuming - and is too expensive for a simple operation like authenticating a user account.

While it does not explain the behaviour of why the try-catch does not catch the error, it did point me to a workable solution using PrincipalContext instead.
This works without any delay or error:
private bool AuthenticateUser(string userName, string password)
{
    using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "EnterYourDomain"))
    {
        return context.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);
    }
}


Use PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null) for default domain.
